# Exclude package from jar in Gradle 6.4.1

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, apache-drill

I am using Gradle 6.4.1 and i am getting conflict for package com.jayway.jsonpath in org.apache.drill.exec:drill-jdbc-all:1.18.0 and spring-boot-starter-data-jpa.

So I want to exclude com.jayway.jsonpath package from drill-jdbc-all.jar

```
 compile ('org.apache.drill.exec:drill-jdbc-all:1.18.0') {
            exclude group: 'com.jayway.jsonpath'
            exclude module: 'json-path'
        }
compile group: 'com.jayway.jsonpath', name: 'json-path', version: '2.4.0'
```

Even tried this

```
configurations {
    all {
        compile.exclude module: 'com.jayway.jsonpath'
    }
}
```

But still its showing
The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

```
    com.jayway.jsonpath.spi.mapper.JacksonMappingProvider: file:/Users/abc/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.drill.exec/drill-jdbc-all/1.18.0/6a0b608238f4a431684cd73d132d7467bc2c3967/drill-jdbc-all-1.18.0.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of com.jayway.jsonpath.spi.mapper.JacksonMappingProvider
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Excluding transitive dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/6.4.1/userguide/dependency_downgrade_and_exclude.html) section of the 6.4.1 docs, give this a try:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation('org.apache.drill.exec:drill-jdbc-all:1.18.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.jayway.jsonpath', module: 'json-path'
    }
    ...
}
```